# How to change the folded part color on Vim

Tags: vim, code-folding

I fold some of the functions on my C code. When I fold them, the color becomes gray. Is there any way to change the color of folded part to another color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `:highlight` setting. For instance, to set the background to red, add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
highlight Folded ctermbg=red
```

You can view a list of supported colour names by running  `:source $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/colortest.vim`. `ctermbg` updates the console background; `ctermfg` updates the console foreground; and `guibg` & `guifg` update gvim's background and foreground colours. If you're changing gvim's settings, you can use whatever hex code you like (you don't have to restrict yourself to supported colours).

Answer (score 2):

Type `:verbose hi` it will describe you all the highlighting groups and where they are defined. There is probably one describing the Fold but I don't know the group name by heart.